# Does AWS-SDK-IOS support for storing Objects in DynamoDB (May be in Json format)?

Tags: json, swift, aws-sdk

I need to store some complex objects in Dynamodb in my IOS mobile application developed with Swift. AS of now What I'm doing is converting the existing object in to a Json String using a third party support, and storing it in a Dynamodb column as a string. And when I want to read it back, I read the json string from the DynamoDB column as a string, and convert it back to the object that I want.

Is this the best way to store objects in Dynamodb when using AWS-SDK-Swift? is there any other support for storing json strings in DynamoDB?

eg:-

```
class Mark
{
 var Subject :String?
 var Score :Int
}

class Student:AWSDynamoDBObjectModel ,AWSDynamoDBModeling
{

var Name :String?
var SID :Int
var Grade :Int
var Dob :String?
var Results :[Mark] =[]

......

}
```

is it possible to save this object directly in to the database? with having the Results array inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes DynamoDB can store JSON like objects to the database.

From the developers guide:

> Document Data Types:
>
> DynamoDB supports List and Map data types, which can be nested to
>   represent complex data structures.
>
> A List type contains an ordered collection of values. A Map type
>   contains an unordered collection of name-value pairs. Lists and maps
>   are ideal for storing JSON documents. The List data type is similar to
>   a JSON array, and the Map data type is similar to a JSON object. There
>   are no restrictions on the data types that can be stored in List or
>   Map elements, and the elements do not have to be of the same type.
>
> The following example shows a Map that contains a String, a Number,
>   and a nested List (which itself contains another Map).
>
> [1]:
>   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataModel.html

You can use a NSDictionary and it will save as a map if i remember correctly.